# Importing videos from iphone

Tags: iphone

I want to import videos from an iPhone . I have 46 videos on the iPhone but only the last 16 have been imported .My knowledge of Ubuntu is very low so I don't know how to proceed .

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? How are you trying to import them?

Answer (score 1):

**I describe the wireless way to copy files from iPhone.**

**Note**: This method does not consume your internet.

**I also created a video on this topic** https://youtu.be/yj2HJinyZgI

---

> Step 1: install `Documents app` on the iPhone.

Documents app link: https://apps.apple.com/in/app/documents-by-readdle/id364901807

> Step 2: Connect your pc to an iPhone hotspot.

- or connect to the same wifi.

> Step 3: open Documents app On iPhone and go to connection / computer option.

> Step 4: you show an URL On Document app.

- In my case, I got `http://172.20.10.1/`

[image: documents app connection computer]

> Step 5: Open your computer browser and write the shown URL address from Document app.

> Step 6 (1): When you enter the address in the PC browser and enter it, the website asks you for the Verification code.

> Step 6 (2): that same time document app show you the Verification code. like the below image.

[image: Pin By Document app]

> Step 6(3): Enter That verification code in your browser.

- Now, You connected with your iPhone.

> Step 7: If You want to access the iPhone gallery.

- go to Albums Folder in Pc browse.
- You got all photos and videos from your iPhone.

> Step 8: Copy video to pc?

- select videos and press the download button.

**Note**: This method does not *consume your internet data*.

[image: Computer Browser]

---

**For Visual steps watch this video** https://youtu.be/yj2HJinyZgI

I have tried my best to explain, but I am sorry if there are any mistakes in explaining

Comment: It looks like the app works only on mac os.

Comment: No, I use it for Ubuntu also. It Works Fine.

You just need a browser nothing else.

Comment: How do you install it to Ubuntu? That link says "This app is available only on the App Store for iPhone and iPad". Got it, sry.

Comment: Thank you , I got as far as the fourth point and got stuck . I clicked on computer and it says "go to https://docstransfer.com on desktop and enter this code to sign in ". However I don't understand where to enter the code

Comment: In ubuntu, you just need to open a browser and paste the given link from the app.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. I also added a video on youtube link: https://youtu.be/yj2HJinyZgI . it helps you a lot more. @Maougna 
.

Comment: Ok , I've got the app free for a week . I've followed your advice and they take for ever to download but I now have several downloads in zipfile form . I would like to put them into shotwell . Is that possible ?

Comment: Thank you for your help . I still am not able to move the photos from downloads into shotwell . I have tried the normal way of dragging them but they don't want to go. My other issue is that I would like to know if there is an  easier way to transfer photos from an iphone because the download app costs and it takes a really long time to  transfer .